# How to malloc/free within OpenMP parallel section?

Tags: c, malloc, openmp, free

I have a few nested for loops, and I'm using #pragma omp parallel around the whole section of code, plus #pragma omp for on the outermost loop. Within the loops, I'm trying to use a double pointer, and then freeing that double pointer when I'm done using it.

However, I've tried 2 different methods and they both are erroring. In the newer version I allocate a large amount of space, so that within the for loops, I create a double pointer that just points to a different section for each iteration; then, I free everything at the end. In the old version, I just allocate and free within the loops for each iteration. How do I fix this?

Newer version:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    double * vals_all = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * 4 * p * q);
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < q; j++) {
            __m256d calc = _mm256_setzero_pd();
            for (int k = 0; k < r / 24 * 24; k += 24) {
                // various SIMD operations changing calc values
            }
            double * vals = vals_all + 4 * i * j;
            _mm256_storeu_pd(vals, calc);
            for (int k = r / 24 * 24; k < r; k++) {
                // various operations using vals
            }
        }
    }
    free(vals_all);
}
```

Older version:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < q; j++) {
            __m256d calc = _mm256_setzero_pd();
            for (int k = 0; k < r / 24 * 24; k += 24) {
                // various SIMD operations changing calc values
            }
            double * vals = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * 4);
            _mm256_storeu_pd(vals, calc);
            for (int k = r / 24 * 24; k < r; k++) {
                // various operations using vals
            }
            free(vals);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `they both are erroring`. Crashing? What is the error exactly?

Comment: Also, do you mean to allocate that _large amount of space_ separate for each thread by placing it inside the `#pragma omp parallel` region? Each thread will allocate its own memory block and operate on it independently of other threads within the for loop.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing. `malloc()` and `free()` were _guaranteed_ to be thread-safe only in the C11 statndard. See if that's the cause?

Comment: Is there a reason for not using static arrays `double vals[4];`?

Comment: In your newer version, watch your addressing: should probably be `double* vals = vals_all + 4*(i*q+j)`. Also, as @Zoso said you're allocating `vals_all` separately for each thread, which is probably not what you meant. Otherwise both variants should work as far as OpenMP is concerned. The error might be something else. Does it also error with just one thread (OMP_NUM_THREADS=1)? And @PaulG. is right that a static-sized array on the stack would be much more efficient for this case.